# Group by relevent two columns

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to group by two columns they are dependent each other

Example:

```
    id          date             status
    1         2016-03-04          0
    2         2016-03-05          0
    3         2016-03-04          1
    4         2016-03-04          0
    5         2016-03-05          1
```

Result:

```
    id          date             status
    1         2016-03-04          0
    2         2016-03-04          0
    3         2016-03-04          1
    4         2016-03-05          0
    5         2016-03-05          1
```

I tried order by datewise and stautswise (ex show 0 status record first after that another date)

pls help me

Comment: please add your query which is used in

Comment: Give examples of your input and expected output

Answer (score 0):

I think you are just looking for a proper `order by`:

```
select t.*
from t
order by date, status;
```

If you want to calculate the `id`, then variables will help:

```
select (@rn := @rn + 1) as id, t.*
from t cross join
     (select @rn := 0) params
order by date, status;
```

Answer (score 0):

As i am getting your requirement it work ......

```
select min(e1.id),min(e1.date),e1.status
from example
inner join result r1 on e1.id =r1.id
group by e1.status
```

if its not your requirement then please let me know i ll update as per your 
requirement.

Answer (score -1):

Use only [Order By Clause](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/order-by-optimization.html) with both column

```
SELECT   *
FROM  tblname
Order By datecol,status
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f8b55/1